# Wiring sectionCollapseButton in NSCollectionViewSectionHeaderView

Tags: cocoa, swift3

From https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscollectionviewsectionheaderview/1644266-sectioncollapsebutton:

> For the best user experience, set this property to the button that
>   lets users control the collapsing of a section so that the collection
>   view can show and hide the button appropriately, based on whether the
>   section’s items can be displayed in the available space. The
>   collection view uses its toggleSectionCollapse(_:) property to access
>   this button.

Not sure how to set this button. Here is my class:

```
import Cocoa

class HeaderView: NSView, NSCollectionViewSectionHeaderView, NSCollectionViewElement {

@IBOutlet weak var collapseButton: NSButton!
...
}
```

If I try:

```
var sectionCollapseButton: NSButton?{
    return collapseButton
}
```

Then I get a warning:

> Var 'sectionCollapseButton' nearly matches optional requirement
>   'sectionCollapseButton' of protocol
>   'NSCollectionViewSectionHeaderView'

It's also impossible to do that this way:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    sectionCollapseButton = collapseButton

    super.awakeFromNib()

    self.sectionCollapseButton = collapseButton
}
```

And it's also impossible to wire it using IB, because there is no such referencing outlet.

Answer (score 0):

When wiring the button from IB, just name the outlet `sectionCollapseButton` instead of `collapseButton`, and make sure the declaration inserted by Xcode matches the signature in [NSCollectionViewSectionHeaderView](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nscollectionviewsectionheaderview/1644266-sectioncollapsebutton):

```
@IBOutlet unowned(unsafe) optional var sectionCollapseButton: NSButton?
```

Comment: There is compiler error *'unowned' may only be applied to class and class-bound protocol types, not 'NSButton?'*

Comment: Even if I change it to weak, which allow me to wire it to IB, that doesn't work also.